# Django using wrong foreign key for joins

Tags: python, django

I have two relationships between models in Django, a many-to-many between `Foo` and `Bar` and a foreign key on `Foo` pointed towards `Bar`.

When I do a query that involves both `Foo` and `Bar`, django insists on using the Foreign Key instead of the M2M to do the join.

(The M2M is the real data here, the Foreign Key is just a bit of caching so I can get the most recent `Bar` created by a certain method.)

So for example (where `foos` is the many-to-many relationship name on `Bar`)

```
Bar.objects.filter(foos__attribute = True)
```

Doesn't return all of the `Bar`s with that attribute, but only the one `Bar` that `Foo` is pointed at with the FK.   How can I force it to use the M2M?  Or is this a bad idea completely?

Comment: Remove `mysql` keyword as it's unrelated.

Comment: Why don't you use the foreign key name in your call to `.filter()`?

Comment: @patrys Sorry my example sucked.  Check again in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and it was definitely an instance of 'should have used real code for the example'.

I had the many-to-many relation on the `Bar` table called 'foos' (lets say).  The foreign key was automatically creating a `related_name` on the `Bar` table called 'foo'.  I was not actually calling:

Bar.objects.filter(foos__attribute = True)

Like I said I was.  I was calling:

Bar.objects.filter(foo__attribute = True)

Which was using the automatically-created related name of the Foreign Key 'foo' instead of the name of the many-to-many table 'foos'.

So lessons learned:

- Don't let django ever decide the related name for you
- Be careful with pluralization!
- Post real examples on SA